# Case statement for Order By clause with Desc/Asc sort

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT *
FROM
    TableName
WHERE
ORDER BY 
    CASE @OrderByColumn
    WHEN 1 THEN Forename
    WHEN 2 THEN Surname
    END;
```

I have a statement like above which lets me dynamically choose how to order the results of a query. However, how do I specify that I want the Forename ordered `DESC` and the Surname `ASC`?

Comment: Please see [this post](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by) and [this might be an interesting read too](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/sql-variant-use-case/).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to split your `ORDER BY` in two parts:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    TableName
WHERE
ORDER BY 
    (CASE @OrderByColumn
    WHEN 1 THEN Forename
    END) DESC -- Forename --> descending
,   (CASE @OrderByColumn
    WHEN 2 THEN Surname
    END) ASC -- Surname --> ascending
```

Comment: can I have more than one column in my order by clause? e.g. `CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 1 THEN Forename, Date END DESC`

Comment: @volumeone Not like that, no. A `CASE` expression returns a single value, so you need to repeat the case with a second column after a comma.

Comment: Hi , How can I add Multiple Columns when met same Case Expression . Example like  (CASE @OrderByColumn
    WHEN 1 THEN Forename, [AnotherColumn]
    END) DESC

Answer (score 7):

You need two clauses in the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @OrderByColumn = 1 and @Dir = 'ASC' THEN Forename
               WHEN @OrderByColumn = 2 and @Dir = 'ASC' THEN Surname
          END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN @OrderByColumn = 1 and @Dir = 'DESC' THEN Forename
               WHEN @OrderByColumn = 2 and @Dir = 'DESC' THEN Surname
          END) DESC
```

Comment: I found this to be a great starting point and this works when the sort columns are the same data type; however, you also need to group the data types similar to how this solution groups ASC and DESC.

Answer (score 3):

another example:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee
ORDER BY 
 CASE WHEN Gender='Male' THEN EmployeeName END Desc,
 CASE WHEN Gender='Female' THEN Country END ASC
```

more details ...http://codechef4u.com/post/2015/04/07/order-by-clause-with-case-expressions-case-statement