# CASE Statement for Order By Clause with Multiple Columns and Desc/Asc Sort

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Following on from my earlier question here [Case statement for Order By clause with Desc/Asc sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949837/case-statement-for-order-by-clause-with-desc-asc-sort) I have a statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    TableName
WHERE
ORDER BY 
    CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 1 THEN Forename END DESC, 
    CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 2 THEN Surname END ASC
```

This works well, but sometimes I need more than column in the order by. I actually need something like this:

```
.....
ORDER BY
    CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 1 THEN Forename, Date, Location END DESC
```

I can't work out how to make the `CASE` statement allow multiple columns in the `THEN` part.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you need this?

```
ORDER BY
    CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 1 THEN Forename END DESC, Date, Location,
    CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 2 THEN Surname END ASC
```

Comment: Won't this sort by `Date` and `Location` regardless?

Comment: in this form you can't specify `Date` or `Location` in second case

Comment: This answer's text formatting is confusing, when @OrderByColumn is 2, it will sort by "NULL, Date, Location, Surname".

Answer (score 36):

You can write multiple cases, even if they all have the same condition.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 1 THEN Forename END DESC, 
    CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 1 THEN Date END, 
    CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 1 THEN Location END, 
    CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 2 THEN Surname END ASC
```

Actually, you don't specify a column to sort by, but an expression.

The case statement returns null if the condition is not met, so actually it means:

```
CASE @OrderByColumn WHEN 1 THEN Forename ELSE NULL END
```

So if @OrderByColumn is not 1 then the statement returns always NULL. That doesn't exclude it from sorting, by the way, but it puts all those rows together in the result, making 'SurName' the decisive sorting within that group of rows.

Comment: by this form you can specify a column more than one time in each separate `@OrderByColumn ` case and best answer

Answer (score 0):

This is better if you want to give sort keyword as well

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Id ASC' THEN Id END ASC,    
CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Id DESC' THEN Id END DESC,
```