# Order by -- different sequence for different criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to do something like this:

```
select a
from table
order by
 case when a='A' then b,c,d
 else d,c,b
```

a, b, c, d are all columns of the the table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048976/case-statement-for-order-by-clause-with-multiple-columns-and-desc-asc-sort

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not that clear about the result that you really expect, bu I suspect that is:

```
order by
    case when a = 'A' then b else d end,
    c,
    case when a = 'A' then d else b end
```

Or if you want records where `a = 'A'` first (with the specified order), and then the rest of the records (with the other sequence), then:

```
order by
    case when a = 'A' then 0 else 1 end,
    case when a = 'A' then b else d end,
    c,
    case when a = 'A' then d else b end
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for causing confusions -- a, b, c, d are all columns of the table.